# How to rotate iCarousel in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, icarousel

I am using iCarousel and `type = carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;`

It's working in my app, but I want rotate another view.

See my image:

[image: iCarousel]

Comment: can u please elaborate more. what do u mean by rotating another view

Comment: another means Right and Left view..

Comment: @Mani any solution for this problem?